# Browserify - Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm working with a couple of node.js modules that I require on the client:

index.js:

```
var sync = require('../lib/sync');
```

So I figured browserify might be the best choice. Bundling the files works great, however, browserify wraps everything in a `(function(){my code here})();` which cause the `Can't find variable: require` error. How can I prevent that behaviour?

When I remove the wrap, everything works as expected without errors.

Comment: Is `index.js` a client or server file? Seems like a server file to me and then no `browserify` needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run browserify with "--exports require", would this be what you need?

```
browserify entry.js --exports require -o br.js
```

Comment: I still get require is not defined. https://gist.github.com/chovy/fd362f5ef09997a97a27

Comment: Same problem here, I still get : Can't find variable require'

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) like this:

```
(function (require) {
    var sync = require('../lib/sync');
}(requre));
```

Comment: But that means I have to wrap the whole code involving 'sync' into the IIFE, which is kind of complicated?